# How do I specify the Data source and XPath binding in WPF

Tags: xml, wpf

In another context, I'm able to use

```
<W3V:FeasibilityPage DataContext="{StaticResource mcf}" />
```

And then within that page I can do

```
<W3V:ObjectList DataContext="{Binding XPath=customer_requirements/mechanisms}" />
```

I want to combine them in one, to do:

```
<W3V:ObjectList DataContext="{StaticResource mcf Binding XPath=customer_requirements/mechanisms}" />
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this. You have to define the `Source` of the binding, then you can use `XPath` against it.

```
<W3V:ObjectList DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource mcf}, XPath=customer_requirements/mechanism}" />
```